# How do I make sure the replaceAll() doesn't leave my String with many spaces?

Tags: java

I am doing this on my String right now: `.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]"," ").toLowerCase()`

Gives me something like this:

```
yg jarang orang perasan  pernah tak korang perasan dlm mickey mouse dulu      http
```

I want to make sure those unnecessary whitespaces are minimized.

I tried `.trim()` but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `+` metacharacter, which means "one or more matches".

```
.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]+"," ").toLowerCase()
```

This will replace one or more non-letter, non-punctuation characters with exactly one space.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]+"," ").toLowerCase()
```

More:

trim() deletes all whitespace characters *before and after* your string. It doesn't touch ones in the middle.